# Como limpar o Global Environment do R?

Tags: r

Qual o comando para limpar o Global Environment do `R`?

Comment: Se não me engano, é esse aqui: rm(list=ls())

Comment: É esse mesmo! Obrigada.

Comment: Eu adicionei como resposta, por favor, aceite clicando no check

Answer (score 1):

Com esse comando você limpa o enviroment do `R`:

```
rm(list=ls())
```